# Unable to redirect to product page in opencart using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a website where I need to redirect the user to the specific page if the user visits the home page for example.

```html
https://evolvesnacks.com should redirect to https://evolvesnacks.com/buysnacks

but

https://evolvesnacks.com/xyz should stay at https://evolvesnacks.com/xyz
```

Comment: Maybe this tutorial can help: https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners

Answer (score 0):

there are many senario to do that so , one of them is the following , put it main root `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/*$     /buysnacks/   [R=302,L]
```

If `buysnacks` is file change it to `buysnacks.whatever`  .
Test it and if every thing goes ok , change `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection.